# How predict_proba in sklearn produces two columns? what are their significance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I was using simple logistic regression to predict  a problem and trying to plot the **precision_recall_curve** and the **roc_curve** with `predict_proba(X_test)`. I checked the docstring of `predict_proba` but hadn't had much details on how it works. I was having bad input every time and checked that `y_test`, `predict_proba(X_test)` doesn't match. Finally discovered `predict_proba()` produces 2 columns and people use the second.

It would be really helpful if someone can give an explanation how it produces two columns and their significance. TIA.

Answer (score 9):

`predict_proba()` produces output of shape (N, k) where N is the number of datapoints and k is the number of classes you're trying to classify. It seems you have two classes and hence you have 2 columns. Say your labels(classes) are ["healthy", "diabetes"], if a datapoint is predicted to have 80% chance of being diabetic and consequently 20% chance of being healthy, then your output row for that point will be [0.2, 0.8] to reflect these probabilities. In general you can go through the predicted array and get probabilities for the k-th class with `model.predict_proba(X)[:,k-1]`

As far as plotting you can do the following for precision_recall_curve:

```
predicted = logisticReg.predict_proba(X_test)
precision, recall, threshold = precision_recall_curve(y_test, predicted[:,1])
```

For ROC:

```
predicted = logisticReg.predict_proba(X_test)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, predicted[:,1])
```

Notice that this will change for multi-label classification. You can find an example of that on the sklearn docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py)

Comment: Thank you so much! But how do i know which colum represents which class probability?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a more full answer to your plotting needs

Answer (score 4):

We can distinguish between the classifiers using the classifier classes. if the classifier name is **model** then **model.classes_** will give the distinct classes.